# android Date object, put in 2 for the day and the getDay returns a 6, why?

Tags: android, date

```
    Date g=new Date(2011-1900, 3, 2);
    int y1=g.getYear();
    int m1=g.getMonth();
    int d1=g.getDay();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have date object you can use that to get value like this

```
Date g=new Date(2011-1900, 3, 2);
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(g);
int month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
int day=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

You should not use the 
`getYear(),getMonth(),getDate() and getDay()` method as they are depracated as [doc says](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html)

Comment: +1 For the idea. I messed almost for 1 hour with old deprecated methods to get my result. Your code helped me. Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

`getDay()` is the day of the week from 0 though 6. Try `g.getDate()`. Though these methods are deprecated, FYI.